# Why was this question closed as off-topic?

Tags: support, closed-questions

[Which sorting algorithm for sorting a lot of exam papers by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023939/which-sorting-algorithm-for-sorting-a-lot-of-exam-papers-by-hand/)

There are actually many questions like this asking for answers for a real life problem as a proxy problem for a programming problem or simply for the sake of its educational value.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a programming question. You asked how *human beings* would sort papers. The considerations in how a gaggle of humans would sort 400 papers are comprehensively unrelated to how a computer would sort 400,000,000.